# Terraform Error launching source instance: timeout while waiting for state to become 'success' (timeout: 15s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have my terraform configured for AWS. I have automated 2 EC2 Instance and 2 ECS Optimized Instance.

I am getting `**Error launching source instance: timeout while waiting for the state to become 'success' (timeout: 15s)**` for all the 4 Instances while I do terraform apply.

I found on some blog that it may be because of inconsistent AMI or misspelled AMI id.

Hence, I have fixed the typo in my AMI id and able to launch 2 instances. However, still, I got the timeout error for the other two instances.

I am using terraform version: 0.9.6
My TF code for ec2 creation:

```
resource "aws_instance" "node1" {
  # ECS-optimized AMI for us-west-2
        ami = "ami-62d35c02"
        instance_type = "t2.medium"
    availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
    security_groups = [
        "${aws_security_group.sg.name}"
    ]
    key_name        = "key"
                tags {
            Name           = "Node Server 1"
        }
        user_data = <<EOF
        #!/bin/bash
        echo ECS_CLUSTER=uat >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
        EOF
        iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.name}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "node2" {
  # ECS-optimized AMI for us-west-2
        ami = "ami-62d35c02"
        instance_type = "t2.medium"
        availability_zone = "us-west-2b"
        security_groups = [
                "${aws_security_group.sg.name}"
        ]
        key_name        = "key"
                tags {
                Name           = "Node Server 2"
        }
        user_data = <<EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                echo ECS_CLUSTER=uat >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
                EOF
                iam_instance_profile = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.name}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "mongo" {
        ami = "ami-63ad4b1b"
        instance_type = "t2.medium"
        availability_zone = "us-west-2c"
        security_groups = [
                "${aws_security_group.sg.name}"
        ]
        key_name        = "key"
                tags {
                Name           = "MongoDB Server"
        }
}

resource "aws_instance" "mysql" {
        ami = "ami-22ac4a5a"
        instance_type = "t2.medium"
        availability_zone = "us-west-2c"
        security_groups = [
                "${aws_security_group.sg.name}"
        ]
        key_name        = "key"
                tags {
                Name           = "MySQL Server"
        }
}
```

Can someone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your actual terraform code

Comment: @RaGe I have updated my code in the question. Please take a look at it.

I have changed the AMI id some times before the error. Would that be an issue?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to identify the underlying issue using the **Terraform Debug Logs**. When I had this error, in my case the issue was that AWS did not have enough capacity for the instance type I was choosing in the availability zone I configured.

A good approach to debug this error would be the following:

1. Set up the `TF_LOG` environment variable to **enable Terraform Debug Logs**. This can be done with the following command on Linux or Mac:

```
export TF_LOG=DEBUG
```

2. Run the `terraform apply` command.
3. When the prompt to apply changes appears write `yes` and hit `Enter` if the plan is okay for you.
4. If you get the error, search for the `[DEBUG]` entries a few lines above it to  identify the underlying issue. To give an example, in my case I found the following:

```
[DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.58.0_x4:
<Response>
  <Errors>
    <Error>
      <Code>InsufficientInstanceCapacity</Code>
      <Message>We currently do not have sufficient t3.medium capacity in the Availability Zone you requested (us-west-1a). Our system will be working on provisioning additional capacity. You can currently get t3.medium capacity by not specifying an
        Availability Zone in your request or choosing us-west-1b.</Message>
    </Error>
  </Errors>
  <RequestID>...</RequestID>
</Response>
```

5. This should allow you to perform corrective actions in your infrastructure to deploy.